# Window positioning not working on some apps

Tags: c#

Good  day to all.

I am trying to change the positioning of a program and move it to `0,0,0` of my screen. I have tried below code:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (var process in processes) {

        Console.WriteLine("Process Name: {0} ", process.ProcessName);

        if (process.ProcessName.Contains("chrome")) {

                  IntPtr handle = process.MainWindowHandle;
                  SetForegroundWindow(handle);
                  SetWindowPos(handle, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
        }
}
MessageBox.Show("OK");
```

The code is working on chrome and notepad but I can't get it work in calculator, explorer and apps not in the taskbar. I've also tried using ProcessId but got no success.

Can I know what I am missing in mycode to make it work?

Thank you very much in advanced for the help.

Comment: What does return `MainWindowHandle` for the problematic programs?

Comment: Hi Alejandro. Thanks for the reply. It is returning zero (0).

Comment: It seems that to me, there is no concept of "main window" in some programs (and I think those that DO work, do so in pure casualty). For example, explorer can open many windows under the same process. What if you enumerate all existing Windows and filter those that are of the interested processes?

Comment: Hi Alejandro. Can you help me with a code to do it. I've already tried: enumerating all the process using Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses(); but still got no success.

Comment: Do it the other way around. Enumerate *windows*, not processes. Here is an example: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Enumerate-top-level-9aa9d7c1, then get to which process it belongs: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com:443/Forums/en-US/0e63cc54-1d6d-44eb-a02c-8cb462eef7dd/get-process-id-from-window-handle?forum=netfxcompact and check if you want to modify it or not. After that, just use your existing code.

Comment: Thank you very much Alejandro. Had it working. :)